# Keep options selected in multiple combobox

Tags: php, mysql, select, combobox, dropdown

this is a code that generates a multiple dropdown list from a MySQL database and creates a table after clicking on a submit button with a selected option by default.

I need the table to be created when the page is loaded and also the dropdown list to keep the options selected after clicking the button.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
include 'conBBDD_1.php';
$db_handle = new conBBDD();
$TourResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT bbcTour FROM concerts ORDER BY bbcDate DESC");
?>

<form method="POST" name="Search" action="example.php">

<?php
  if (! empty($TourResult)) {
        $format = "Tour 2020";
        $select = 'selected';
        echo "<select name='tour[]' id='bb_tour' multiple='multiple'>";
   foreach ($TourResult as $key => $value) {
   echo "<option value='" . $TourResult[$key]['bbcTour']."'";
   if($TourResult[$key]['bbcTour']==$format) // to select one option only
            echo $select. ">";
        else
            echo ">";

            echo $TourResult[$key]['bbcTour'].'</option>' . "\n";
      }
    }
            echo "</select>";
?>
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="OK">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the issue, but have cleaned this up for you.

If the issue is that (like your comment) you just want *one* item to be selected, remove the 'multiple' attribute from the select tag here.

Otherwise the 'multiple' tag and 'selected' just need to be lone strings w/ values.

```php
<?php

  include 'conBBDD_1.php';
  $db_handle = new conBBDD();
  $TourResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT bbcTour FROM concerts ORDER BY bbcDate DESC");

  echo '<form method="POST" name="Search" action="example.php">';

  echo "<select name='tour[]' id='bb_tour' multiple>";

  if (!empty($TourResults)) {

    $format = "Tour 2020";

    foreach ($TourResults as $Tour) {

      echo "<option value='" . $Tour . "'";

      if($Tour === $format) {

            echo ' selected';

      }


    }

    echo ">" . $Tour . "</option>\n";

  }

  echo "</select>";

  echo "</form>";

?>
```

Comment: The code already selects one item when the page loads. What I would need is that the combobox keeps the options selected each time the user clicks the button when doing a query,